# How do I scale my Azure application without having a temporary outage?

Tags: windows, api, azure, azure-web-roles

I'm toying with Windows Azure Management API for scaling my Azure web role. At some point I have one instance and decide that I want to go from one instance to two instances. I send an HTTP POSt request to

```
https://management.core.windows.net:443/<my-subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<my-service-name>/deployments/<my-deployment-name>/?comp=config
```

with an XML specifying the same configuration as deployment currently has and instances count set to two. The call succeeds and the change starts. Now for about 30 seconds the web role will not accept HTTP calls - the caller will get

```
10061 connection refused
```

in browser. Which means the role is not serving client requests. That's a problem.

How do I scale the web role in such way that it serves client requests at all times?

Comment: Does it block calls, if you go from 2 to 3. I am just wondering if it is due to the fact you only have 1 instance running. I have commonly scaled up and down from 2-4 and never experienced any downtime during those periods.

Comment: For me, if I go down from 3 to 1, the remaining instance restarts... I think its because I am going down to 1 and the SLA requires > 1 instance

Comment: @Ilyas: No, that's not because of SLA, that's likely because you handle on of `RoleEnvironment` events in such way that Azure decided to restart the instance. You asked a separate question about that http://stackoverflow.com/q/16907000/57428

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [SLA](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/sla/) (Service Level Agreement - Compute):

> We guarantee that when you deploy **two or more role instances** in
>   different fault and upgrade domains your Internet facing roles will
>   have external connectivity at least 99.95% of the time.

This means that having one instance is not supported case for SLA, so you may (or will) have downtime. If scale from 2 or more, or from more to 2, there shall not be any outage.

[This blog post](http://blog.toddysm.com/2010/04/upgrade-domains-and-fault-domains-in-windows-azure.html) outlines a good explanation about fault and upgrade domains. Before all, scaling means "upgrade" - you are changing configuration, this configuration change needs to be propagaded through all roles and instances. The only way to do that witout downtime (currently) is to have at least two instances, each of which lives in separate domain.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, when you have 2 instances or more, you might still experience an outage when you modify the service configuration (like changing the number of instances using the Service Management API). Any configuration change will trigger a reboot of your instances.

To prevent this you'll need to implement the following code in your WebRole.cs/WorkerRole.cs (and as a result you won't have an outage when you change the number of instances):

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
    RoleEnvironment.Changing += RoleEnvironmentChanging;
    return base.OnStart();
}

private void RoleEnvironmentChanging(object sender, RoleEnvironmentChangingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Changes.Any(change => change is RoleEnvironmentConfigurationSettingChange))
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** See astaykov's comment below.

Comment: What exactly will that change do?

Comment: e.Cancel = false will prevent role from recycling. However, if you have some logic in your application which relies on setting in the azure configuration, you have explicitly handle this configuration change. You have to also hook the RoleEnvironmentChanged, so if you prevented the recycling, you must trigger rereading the configuration settings.

Comment: @Sandrino, I tend to not agree about your statement. This is the idea of having two instances at least, and they running in different Upgrade/fault domains. The process shall first update one of your instances, then, when it is fully recovered, update the other. You may check the links I provided in my answer, or find yourself more details on fault and upgrade domains.

Comment: @astaykov, you are right, I didn't take into account the upgrade domains.