# Azure cloud service becomes unresponsive when instances are removed?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

My azure cloud service, when it scales down say from 3 to 2 instances, my site becomes unresponsive for a few minutes?

I was under the impression, and I may be wrong that my existing instances would be left intact (except those that are being removed) and my site would continue to function as normal?

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 4):

- This is expected behavior when you scale down from 2 instances to 1 as you are no longer in the SLA-backed world.
- This is also expected behavior if the RoleEnvironmentChanging event of your WebRole sets e.Cancel to "true" which forces instance-reboots during a scaling event.

Otherwise, scale-down actions should not cause interruptions to your site

Comment: Really? Imagine I have instance A and B running, are you suggesting then if I scale up to C and D and then when I scale down back to just A, A will restart too? Why does A need to restart? Surly they are independant instances?

Comment: Would this not happen if I scaled down from 4 to 2 instances, but would happen if I scaled from 4 to 1?

Comment: Correct.  Anytime you work with 1 instance and perform a configuration operation (from Azure portal or thru a scaling tool) Azure recycles the only instance for some unknown reason

Comment: This is not quite correct.  Azure will not recycle an instance during a config change or scale operation unless you set e.Cancel=true.

When you scale down, the only thing that happens with the remaining instances is that they will get a RoleEnvironmentTopologyChange if you have internal endpoints defined (implicit if you have RDP enabled).  By default this topology change event will not recycle the remaining role instances.  They will only recycle if you set e.Cancel=true.

Comment: kwill, I agree in principal, unfortunately evidence points to contrary.  Have seen numerous times when this happens w/o e.Cancel = true